# How to performe openJPA enhancement at runtime?

Tags: java, deployment, openjpa, apache-tomee

I am trying to deploy dynamic web project with openJPA faset to the TomEE Plus server. However, when I launch application on the server it gives me the following error:

> 111  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - OpenJPA dynamically loaded a validation provider.
>   131  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.2.0
>   202  INFO   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary".

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types 
were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: "
    de.webshop.internal.db.Producer
    de.webshop.internal.db.Stock
    de.webshop.internal.db.Product".

at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:115)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:314)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:238)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:60)
at de.webshop.inventory.service.business.logic.utils.ProductAvailabilityInStock.isEnoughProductsInStock(ProductAvailabilityInStock.java:43)
at de.webshop.inventory.service.implementation.InventoryWebService.CheckOrderItemsAvailability(InventoryWebService.java:52)
at test.de.webshop.TestClass.testWBService(TestClass.java:40)
at test.de.webshop.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:12)
```

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can either enhance at build-time or you need to define an agent for runtime enhancement like: "*java -javaagent:./lib/openjpa-all-2.2.2.jar ... com.xyz.Main*"